# How do I use an environment in an ML Azure Pipeline

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

**Background**

I have created an ML Workspace environment from a conda `environment.yml` plus some docker config and environment variables. I can access it from within a Python notebook:

```
env = Environment.get(workspace=ws, name='my-environment', version='1')
```

I can use this successfully to run a Python script as an experiment, i.e.

```
runconfig = ScriptRunConfig(source_directory='script/', script='my-script.py', arguments=script_params)
runconfig.run_config.target = compute_target
runconfig.run_config.environment = env
run = exp.submit(runconfig)
```

**Problem**

I would now like to run this same script as a Pipeline, so that I can trigger multiple runs with different parameters. I have created the Pipeline as follows:

```
pipeline_step = PythonScriptStep(
    source_directory='script', script_name='my-script.py',
    arguments=['-a', param1, '-b', param2],
    compute_target=compute_target,
    runconfig=runconfig
)
steps = [pipeline_step]
pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=steps)
pipeline.validate()
```

When I then try to run the Pipeline:

```
pipeline_run = Experiment(ws, 'my_pipeline_run').submit(
    pipeline, pipeline_parameters={...}
)
```

I get the following error: `Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Conda dependencies were not specified. Please make sure that all conda dependencies were specified i).`

When I view the pipeline run in the Azure Portal it seems that the environment has not been picked up: none of my conda dependencies are configured, hence the code does not run. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're almost there, but you need to use `RunConfiguration` instead of `ScriptRunConfig`. More info [here](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-getting-started.ipynb)

```py
from azureml.core.runconfig import RunConfiguration

env = Environment.get(workspace=ws, name='my-environment', version='1')
# create a new runconfig object
runconfig = RunConfiguration()
runconfig.environment = env

pipeline_step = PythonScriptStep(
    source_directory='script', script_name='my-script.py',
    arguments=['-a', param1, '-b', param2],
    compute_target=compute_target,
    runconfig=runconfig
)

pipeline = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=[pipeline_step])

pipeline_run = Experiment(ws, 'my_pipeline_run').submit(pipeline)
```