# How do I version control Azure ML workspaces with custom environments and pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to figure out how viable Azure ML in production; I would like to accomplish the following:

1. Specify *custom environments* for my pipelines using a *pip file* and use them in a pipeline
2. *Declaratively* specify my workspace, environments and pipelines in an *Azure DevOps repo*
3. *Reproducibly* deploy my Azure ML workspace to my subscription using an *Azure DevOps pipeline*

I found an [explanation of how to specify environments using notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506398/how-do-i-use-an-environment-in-an-ml-azure-pipeline) but this seems ill-suited for the second and third requirements I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, we have a python script, `pipeline.py` that uses the `azureml-sdk`to create, register and run all of our ML artifacts (envs, pipelines, models). We call this script in our Azure DevOps CI pipeline with a Python Script task after building the right pip env from the requirements file in our repo.

However, it is worth noting there is YAML support for ML artifact definition. Though I don't know if the existing support will cover all of your bases (though that is the plan).

Here's some great docs from MSFT to get you started:

- [GitHub Template repo of an end-to-end example of ML pipeline + deployment](https://github.com/microsoft/MLOpsPython)
- [How to define/create an environment (using Pip or Conda) and use it in a remote compute context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments)
- [Azure Pipelines guidance on CI/CD for ML Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-machine-learning?context=azure%2Fmachine-learning%2Fservice%2Fcontext%2Fml-context&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [Defining ML pipelines in YAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/reference-pipeline-yaml)